# What type to use for terms aggregation?

Tags: typescript, elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch terms aggregation to grab the unique values of a few fields:

```js
    {
      // query removed for brevity
      aggs: {
        provinces: {
          terms: { field: "shipping_address.province.keyword" }
        },
        shipping_carriers: {
          terms: { field: "fulfillments.tracking_company.keyword" }
        },
        shipping_methods: {
          terms: { field: "shipping_lines.title.keyword" }
        }
      }
    }
```

This results in a response where the `aggregations` look like:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "shipping_carriers" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "FedEx",
          "doc_count" : 31
        },
        //...removed for brevity
      ]
    },
    "provinces" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 8,
      "buckets" : [
         //...removed for brevity
      ]
    },
    "shipping_methods" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
         //...removed for brevity
      ]
    },
    "shipping_codes" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
         //...removed for brevity
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the Javascript [library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html) with Typescript.

I'm still sort of new to Typescript, and I can't figure out what types to use for the `buckets` so I can access the `key` as a `string`.

```js
      // ???: what are the correct types to use here?
      const aggs = results.aggregations as Record<
        string,
        AggregationsTermsAggregateBase<AggregationsCompositeBucketKeys>
      >;
      
      // ???: `any[]` is bad, what are the proper types to use?
      const province_buckets = aggs.provinces.buckets as any[];
      const carrier_buckets = aggs.shipping_carriers.buckets as any[];
      const method_buckets = aggs.shipping_methods.buckets as any[];

      return new OrderFilters({
        provinces: province_buckets.map((bucket) => bucket.key),
        shipping_carriers: carrier_buckets.map((bucket) => bucket.key),
        shipping_methods: method_buckets.map((bucket) => bucket.key)
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and found a PR in the Elastic repo - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/pull/1596 -> test/unit/api.test.ts

```
interface Aggregations {
  unique: T.AggregationsTermsAggregateBase<{ key: string }>
}

const response = await client.search<Doc, Aggregations>({
    index: 'test',
    allow_no_indices: true,
    query: { match_all: {} },
    aggregations: {
      unique: {
        terms: {
          field: 'foo'
        }
      }
    }
  })

  t.equal(response.hits.hits[0]._source?.foo, 'bar')
  t.ok(Array.isArray(response.aggregations?.unique.buckets))
```